# Outlook shows all day events in adjacent time zones on two days

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

If someone in an adjacent time zone puts in an all day event, it shows up on my calendar as 11pm-11pm.  And mine show up on his as 1am-1am.  This is NOT what we mean.  Is there a way to have outlook understand that an all day event from an adjacent time zone means simply that, i.e. just that one day?

[image: All Day Event Looks Wrong]

[image]

Comment: Why not use the working day instead of all day? Or 1am - 11pm? It would be very difficult for any calendar to know when you would want your time zone and when his. For example, if he needed to make a payment on a particular day in his time zone, then you would need to know the dead-line in your time zone (ie shifted). There would be no point in calling to remind him half an hour before midnight your time if it was half an hour after his deadline.

Comment: The interface allows entry of time, and has a check-box that says 'all day event'.  We are using the 'all-day-event' checkbox for the time instead of using specific times.  Thus when we click on that box we mean THAT day.  It is outlook that is turning it into times.

Comment: @AFH Apparently, sometimes it's 1AM rather than midnight. Try Asuncion timezone, for example. I suspect Outlook does this because midnight on the first day of DST does not exist since it starts at 23:59:59.999 on Saturday.

Comment: @VictorEngel - I am in UK, and if I ask someone to call me on a particular day, I mean _my_ day. I don't expect a call at 4am the following morning because it is still the previous day in US. So if an event is scheduled for a particular day it means that day in the time zone where the event occurs, which of course is different time ranges in other time zones.

Comment: @AFH, I don't know what that has to do with my comment.

Comment: @VictorEngel - The point is that it doesn't matter what happens at the start and end of DST: the only significant time zone is that where the event occurs. When DST starts there will be a 23-hour day, and which hour is skipped is irrelevant: the event's time zone will (I hope) still be correctly translated to the observer's time zone - and my original suggestion of using 01:00 to 23:00 for adjacent time zones is unaffected by the point you make in your comment.

Comment: @AFH, first, there are two kinds of events. One kind, like meetings, have to happen at the same instants. Others, like New Year's Day and Christmas are at different times around the world. I think that is what the OP was trying to do.

Anyway, my point that Outlook treats all day event sometimes as 1AM to 1AM rather than midnight to midnight as the OP was intimating, still stands, irrespective of whatever kludge you are suggesting to work around the problem. Perhaps I erred in pinging you instead of the OP. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am looking for.  The 'New Years'/'Christmas' experience.  The interface allows me/others to say 'all day', I want people in nearby TZs to see that as 'all day' and not 11-11 or 1-1.  Which causes the event to be on two days.  I think what has to happen is that the people that make OUTLOOK need to recognize that in addition to be 'global' we are often 'regional' as well.  And all-day in an adjacent TZ means all-day in mine and not 11-11 or 1-1.

Answer (score 2):

The product is working as designed. An all day event is a full 24 hours from midnight to midnight. A colleague in a different time zone (according to your hours) will see the event differently. There is no solution. There is only a workaround to mark your event within business hours that do not cross days.

Outlook has been working this way for over 10 years. I seriously doubt Microsoft will change how the time zone behavior works.

Source: [Workaround for all day events that span two days across time zones in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/262451?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: I get the fact that businesses are global and someone's 'all day' event on the other side of the world from me has to be considered with time-of-day element where I am.  But with that said, it is very inconvenient that Outlook won't give me 'fudge-factor' so that an all-day-event in an adjacent timezone could look like it occurs on a single day.

Comment: As stated in the original question, That is exactly the opposite of what I want.